# No program header covering vaddr 0xFFFF.... found kexec bug?

Tags: linux, crash, kernel, kexec

I am trying to make use of kexec / kdump stuffs to debug kernel crashes.
I am able to load the crash kernel successfully and I am able to dump the vmcore from crash kernel.

Process /proc/vmcore ...
     0 -r--------    1 root     root        3.8G Jan  1 00:02 /proc/vmcore

But when I try to use vmcore-dmesg to extract the crash log I am getting the below error and the crash log file is 0 byte.

Generate crash log:
No program header covering vaddr 0xffffff8008ba3560found kexec bug?
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             0 Jan  1 00:02 crash.log

When I did some research on this I found a patch related to this (https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/9273231/). But, it didn't help.

main kernel and crash kernel versions are different. Do I need to use same version for both the kernels?
any idea on this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is fixed after using same version kernel for MAIN app and crash app. And upgraded the kexec tools to 2.0.19.